# Is there a list of propreties could be used on Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have used some properties to deploy my task on Spring Cloud Data Flow. For example:

```
spring.cloud.dataflow.features.schedules-enabled: true
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=
```

However I can not found any documents about the summary of these properties. How can I discover more properties to apply to my project? And I have also confused about ":" or "=". Which one is valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to Spring official website for this.

Take `2.0.0.RELEASE` for example, you can find **Common application properties** [HERE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html).

And for Spring Cloud Data Flow, you can find **Configuration** [HERE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration) for Local/PCF/K8s.

Or if you are using STS(Spring Tool Suite) as your IDE, you can also find a list of allowable properties while keying property in `.properties` or `.yml` files.

Comment: How about : trigger.time-unit, trigger.fixed-delay, trigger.cron, trigger.initial-delay. Can I use it as Common application properties

Comment: Those properties are for **Time Source** in `spring-cloud-stream-app-starters`, I am nor sure what you mean using them as Common application properties.